# How to do intermediate process in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of string that look like that :

```
['1 2 3 4 5', '1 2 3 4 5',...]
```

And I want for example only the third and fifth element of each string :

```
[(3,5), (3,5),...]
```

how can I do something like this :

```
[(ans[2],ans[4]); ans.split() for ans in answers]
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get multiple items from different indices:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = ['1 2 3 4 5', '1 2 3 4 5']

f = itemgetter(2, 4)             # get third and fifth items
r = [f(x.split()) for x in lst]
print(r)
# [('3', '5'), ('3', '5')]
```

Cool thing is, it also works with slice objects:

```
f = itemgetter(2, 4, slice(3, 0, -1))
r = [f(x.split()) for x in lst]
print(r)
# [('3', '5', ['4', '3', '2']), ('3', '5', ['4', '3', '2'])]
```

Answer (score 6):

You **first perform a mapping**, for instance **using a genrator**:

```
(ans.split() for ans in answers)
```

and then you **iterate over the generator**, and **process the intermediate result further**, like:

```
[(imm[2],imm[4]) for imm in (ans.split() for ans in answers)]
```

generating:

```
>>> [(imm[2],imm[4]) for imm in (ans.split() for ans in answers)]
[('3', '5'), ('3', '5')]
```